# Prove this subset is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a $F$, a field, and the Vector Space of polynomials with coefficients form $F$, $P(F)$.  Furthermore, consider a subset of elements from $P$, $S$, such that no two elements in $S$ have the same degree.  Prove that the subset is linearly independent.

I think the best way to do this is to use proof by contradiction.  Consider the contrary, that the set is linearly dependant.  That would mean I could write at least 1 element as a linear combination of the other elements.  But I am not sure what the contradiction would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing one polynomial as a linear combination of the other polynomials, we should write the zero polynomial as a linear combination of the polynomials in $S$.

*Hint*: From here, consider the polynomial of largest degree with a non-zero coefficient in this linear combination.

Comment: I couldn't write the zero polynomial as a linear combo of the elements, since I can't get rid of the polynomial of largest degree.

Comment: @DemetriP: There's your contradiction.

Comment: How can I put that mathematically?

Comment: (Caveat: this only works if $S$ is finite.  It seems much harder if $S$ is allowed to be infinite [is it even true?].)  But to phrase this "the zero polynomial can only be formed as a linear combination of the polynomials in $S$ trivially" or something along those lines.  "Hence $S$ is linearly independent."

Comment: @Rebecca: $S$ is linearly independent if no nontrivial *finite* linear combination of its elements gives $0$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that.  Well then this proof works in that case too.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For scalars $\alpha_i\ne 0$ and pairwise diffrerent polynomials $s_i\in S$, we have $$\deg\left(\sum_i\alpha_is_i\right)=\max_i(\deg(s_i))\,.$$

Comment: This isn't always true.  Imagine the polynomials $x^3+x-1$ and $-x^3$.  This violates your relation. EDIT: Unless I pick nice constants.  Thanks.

Comment: The hypothesis was: '*no two elements in $S$ have the same degree*'.